# javascript input field onchange causes "is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I have a function i would like to run onChange. This works fine with an a-tag. But when i use it on an input-tag it just says:

**form.saveFile is not a function**

This works:

```
<a onclick="form.saveFile('fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb','fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest'); return false;" href="#">Upload file</a>
```

This does NOT work:

```
<input onchange="form.saveFile('fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb','fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest');" id="fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest" class="file" type="file"  name="fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest" accesskey="F"/>
```

Both calls the same form.saveFile(); function.

The form variable is declared in a included js file like this:

```
form = {
  version: '1.0.0',
  ...alot of functions... 
  saveFile : function(callback,p){
    .................
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the `form` variable come from? Where did you declare it?

Comment: Please post a minimal snipped of html + javascript code that reproduces the problem (both the working a onclick and the non-working input onchange).

Comment: I did post 2 html snippets. One working and one not working. a onclick works. but input onchange says the function is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form` is a reserved word in a `onchange` handler. Just rename your variable and it will work:

```
var frm = {
    version: '1.0.0',
    saveFile : function(callback,p){
    }
};

<input onchange="frm.saveFile('fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb','fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest');" id="fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest" class="file" type="file"  name="fec056b774ffefa479c7dd3a632275cb_filetest" accesskey="F"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside forms `form` does refer to that specific `form` element. So you need to distinguish between the `form` that’s referring to the `form` element and your `form` variable. You can do so with using `window.form` if you defined your `form` variable in the global scope. Or you just rename it.

Answer (score 0):

need more info. did you try in all browsers? it should work. If the text has been changed, once the focus leaves the text box onchange will occur. try using alert() to test if the function is really called. there could be something wrong with your function. hope this helps.

Comment: I tried in most browsers. First one was firefox. 
Alert(1); in both a-tag and input-tag works fine. But i cannnot access form.saveFile from the input-onchange. Only from a-onclick

Comment: try using document.getElementById('form_id'). since ids are unique, you wont get any problem when referring to elements in html page.